# Can an XML document reference an external parsed entity of different XML version?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

Suppose we have an XML 1.0 document `xml10.xml` which references an external parsed entity `xml11.ent`, where `xml11.ent` has a text declaration of `<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>`. Is this legal? What if `xml11.ent` uses features which are not supported by XML 1.0, such as entity references to control characters (e.g. `&#1;`) or unbinding prefixes (e.g. `xmlns:foo=""`)?

Conversely, we can ask the same questions about an XML 1.1 document including an XML 1.0 external parsed entity.

**Clarification**: I am interested in what if anything the XML specifications require, not how any particular implementation may behave. Answers that reference the relevant specifications would be particularly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the parser supports the most recent version which is being referenced: yes, that should work. (Whether it actually does or not is a quality-of-implementation issue you'll have to take up with that parser's authors.)

Comment: I should have made clearer in the question, my interest is not how any particular implementation behaves, but what if anything the specifications themselves require.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the XML 1.1 spec has no problem with external parsed entities that are XML 1.0. The other way around, of course, is unspecified but I would expect it to work if you have a 1.1-capable parser.